# Valid xPath expression in Google Inspector, but not in Scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape a meetup page using Scrapy (I am only trying to get the name and the urls of the groups), but for some reason, the xpath selector doesn't return anything in the terminal (I'm using the scrapy shell method), whereas it seems valid in Google Inspector. 
You can see my code in Scrapy below :

```
In [15]: groups = response.xpath("//li[@class='groupCard tileGrid-tile  noRatings']/div/a[contains(@class, 'display-non
    ...: e')]")

In [16]: groups
Out[16]: []

In [17]: groups = response.xpath("//li[@class='groupCard tileGrid-tile  noRatings']/div/a[contains(@class, 'display-none')]").get()

In [18]: groups

In [19]:
```

and the [Google Inspector screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNQaY.png) here.
Do you guys have any idea of what I am doing wrong ? thanks !

Comment: are you sure the page is loaded successfully by the time you try to access the elements with the xpath? And also check if the element is present in the iframe.

Comment: Are you using Splash? Otherwise you probably won't get the same thing.

Comment: @pguardiario I'm not using Splash, but I have disabled Javascript using the Inspector, it's not enough ?

Comment: It seems like it should be. You should save that response and load it in chrome.